# Vue 3 Composition Api - Find object and render

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, error-handling, render

I have a problem. It's my first Vue.js project and I need help to solve the following problem. First I get a response from my API, then I get a list of projects and I want to find the project with the same ID as the url parameter. When I try to open the view my console logs the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

However, it then renders the right project into the template.

Code:

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <Sidebar></Sidebar>
    <div id="content">
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <div id="headline">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h1>Projekt Details</h1>
            <Popup></Popup>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="grid" class="module-grid module-grid-2">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-head">
            <div>
              <h3>Meta Daten</h3>
            </div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <ul v-if="filtered_projects != null">
              <li>
                <div class="list-info">
                  <p>Projektnummer: {{ filtered_projects.id }}</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="list-info">
                  <p>Autor: {{ filtered_projects.author }}</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="list-info">
                  <p>Firma: {{ filtered_projects.company }}</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="list-info">
                  <p>
                    Erstellt am: 
                    {{
                      new Date(filtered_projects.created_at)
                        .toLocaleString()
                        .split(",")[0]
                    }}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="list-info">
                  <p>
                    Letzte Änderung am: 
                    {{
                      new Date(filtered_projects.updated_at)
                        .toLocaleString()
                        .split(",")[0]
                    }}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-head">
            <div>
              <h3>Projekt Übersicht</h3>
            </div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form class="edit-form" @submit.prevent="submitProject()">
              <label for="title">Überschrift*</label>
              <input
                v-model="filtered_projects.title"
                name="title"
                id="title"
                class="input"
                type="text"
                required
                maxlength="16"
              />
              <label for="text">Text*</label>
              <textarea
                v-model="filtered_projects.text"
                name="text"
                id="text"
                class="input"
                type="text"
                required
                rows="6"
              />
              <label for="finish">Abgeschlossen</label>
              <input
                v-model="filtered_projects.finish"
                name="finish"
                id="finish"
                class="input w-auto"
                type="checkbox"
              />
              <button v-if="state.user_info.id === filtered_projects.author || state.user_info.admin === true" type="submit" class="second-btn btn">
                Aktualisieren
              </button>
            </form>
             <button v-on:click="deleteProject()" v-if="state.user_info.id === filtered_projects.author || state.user_info.admin === true" class="btn delete-btn">Löschen</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, reactive } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { useRoute, useRouter } from "vue-router";
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar.vue";
import Popup from "../components/Popup.vue";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.vue";

export default {
  name: "ProjectDetails",
  components: {
    Sidebar,
    Popup,
    Navbar,
  },
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const route = useRoute();
    const router = useRouter();

    store.dispatch("company_projects/getProjectList");
    store.dispatch("user_info/getUserInfo");
    store.dispatch("companies/getCompaniesList");

    const state = reactive({
      query: route.params.id,
      company_projects: computed(
        () => store.getters["company_projects/getProjectlist"]
      ),
      user_info: computed(
        () => store.getters["user_info/getUserInfo"]
      ),
      companies: computed(
        () => store.getters["companies/getCompanieslist"]
      ),
      user_auth_data: computed(
        () => store.getters["auth/getAuthData"]
      ),
    });

    const filtered_projects = computed(() => state.company_projects.find(obj => {
      return obj.id == parseInt(state.query)
    }))

    async function submitProject() {

      await store
        .dispatch("company_projects/submitProject", {
          id: state.company_project.id,
          company: state.company_project.company,
          author: state.company_project.author,
          title: state.company_project.title,
          text: state.company_project.text,
          finish: state.company_project.finish,
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }); 
    }

    async function deleteProject() {


      await store
        .dispatch("company_projects/deleteProject", {
          id: state.company_project.id,
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }); 

        router.push("/project");
    }

    return {
      state,
      submitProject,
      deleteProject,
      filtered_projects,
      route,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Do you know a way to solve it better than me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: **filtered_projects** is computed, sou you should not pass it for **v-model**, or you can define **getter** and **setter** for **filtered_projects** to use it for **v-model**

Comment: I don't see any `computed` used in `v-model` - only properties of object returned by `computed`, which is absolutely fine. The problem is not `computed` but the fact that the object is coming from the store. So mutating it's properties directly by `v-model` will throw an error if the store is configured to [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dispatching the `company_projects/getProjectList` action (which I suppose is responsible for fetching data from the server) directly in the setup, it is very likely that at the moment your component will render for the 1st time, the `company_projects/getProjectList` getter (and consequently the `state.company_projects` computed) will return an empty array and thus `filtered_projects` is `undefined` ([find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find))

Which means the part of your template which needs `filtered_projects` to have a value should be protected with `v-if`

```html
<form class="edit-form" @submit.prevent="submitProject()" v-if="filtered_projects">
```